# Can you start Myrrix with pre-calculated model?

Tags: myrrix

I noticed myrrix creates a file within a tmp directory that is like a model.
Can I start myrrix with this information in order to save time and not have to re-ingest the data.

```
Sat Jan 18 10:03:09 EST 2014 INFO Writing model to /tmp/DelegateGenerationManager7633240206665163912.bin.gz
Sat Jan 18 10:03:55 EST 2014 INFO Done, moving into place at /tmp/1390056408253-0/model.bin.gz
Sat Jan 18 10:03:57 EST 2014 INFO Pruning old entries...
Sat Jan 18 10:03:57 EST 2014 INFO Recomputing generation state...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just put a `model.bin.gz` in the local directory that it's running over. That could be a model you saved separately. You could also create one manually, although that would require some hacking on the code to serialize your own model.